# PySerial can't read data from Arduino on a PyQt5 GUI

Tags: python, serial-port, pyqt5, pyserial

I'm trying to create a GUI application in order to send and receive data to an Arduino using PyQt5 and PySerial. However, it can't write any data to the Arduino.

I've already tried to import the library on the Python Console and tried to send/receive data and succeeded.

```py
    def connectArduino(self):
        self.port = self.serialList[self.serialBox.currentIndex()]
        if len(self.port) < 2:
            errorWindow = QMessageBox()
            errorWindow.critical(self, "Error", "Arduino not selected.")
        else:
            ex.serial = SerialInterface(9600, self.port)
            ex.serial.serial.flush()
            ex.serial.write("id")
            time.sleep(5)
            teststr = ex.serial.read()
            print("Output: " + teststr)
            if teststr == "OK":
                self.serialButton.setText("Connected")
                self.serialButton.setDisabled(True)
                self.serialBox.setDisabled(True)
                self.serialButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
            else:
                errorWindow = QMessageBox()
                errorWindow.critical(self, "Error", "Selected serial port is not valid.")
                ex.serial.close()
```

Edit: I've added an LED to the Arduino where I set it to blink when it receives data. When triggered from console, the LED blinks however when the function is called from GUI, there is no difference.

Comment: Do you really need such a long waiting time between reading and writing? You might be getting timeout on your Arduino.

Comment: I've tried several waiting times in the range of 0-5, but none of them achieved anything.

Comment: But the same code work on the console? Strange...